# Can't get prebuild hooks to work in Trigger.io

Tags: coffeescript, trigger.io

I'm keen to use coffeescript within Trigger.io and to do so I am following the details as described at http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/tools/hooks.html

I've placed my coffeescript.js file in the hooks/prebuild directory as required but the build now fails. I've commented out everything in the coffeescript.js file to ensure it's not the file's contents.

It detects the coffeescript.js file in the prebuild directory as shown in the log output but then it can't find some file. Anyone else have this problem? I'm using version 1.4 of the Trigger Toolkit.

```
[INFO] Running (node) hook: coffeescript.js
[DEBUG] Running: 'node' '/Users/Will/forge-workspace/alpha-timing/hooks/prebuild/coffeescript.js' 'ios'
[ERROR] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you fix this? it is discouraging

Answer (score 2):

A slight tangent... but you might want to have a look at Brunch.io

I've recently started using it for building the JS for my trigger.io app and it works great. It can compile your coffeescript, js, css and more automatically. Comes with a watcher and auto-reload, so when you are developing and testing in browser it's very fast.

Answer (score 1):

We use Node.js to transform the coffeescript into JS at the prebuild stage - it looks like you don't have it installed: go to http://nodejs.org/ to grab it.

Note you'll also need [coffee-script](https://npmjs.org/package/coffee-script) to run that hook!

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I definitly have node and coffee-script installed.

Comment: we are also having the problem. what could be the issue? I could run the test script on the node console, so it is definitely not a problem there